# 10001 Internal Error when trying to capture an authorization from PayPal with Activemerchant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soap, paypal, activemerchant

I've successfully made authorized a card, and it shows up in my sandbox transaction log.  When I try to capture using that authorization (with activemerchant, which uses SOAP), this is the XML it sends to the server:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <env:Header>
        <RequesterCredentials xmlns:n1="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xmlns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI" env:mustUnderstand="0">
            <n1:Credentials>
                <Username>seller_1249669053_per_api1.synergyeoc.com</Username>
                <Password>snip</Password>
                <Subject/>
            </n1:Credentials>
        </RequesterCredentials>
    </env:Header>
    <env:Body>
        <DoCaptureReq xmlns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI">
            <DoCaptureRequest xmlns:n2="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
                <n2:Version>52.0</n2:Version>
                <AuthorizationID>0RF01309N5838270B</AuthorizationID>
                <Amount currencyID="USD">2600.00</Amount>
                <CompleteType>Complete</CompleteType>
                <Note/>
            </DoCaptureRequest>
        </DoCaptureReq>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Paypal returns the ever so descriptive 10001 "Internal Error." Can anyone spot what's not right here?

Just for fun, here is what ActiveMerchant parses as the response from paypal:

```
=> #<ActiveMerchant::Billing::Response:0x3e00698 @params={"payment_status"=>"None", "correlation_id"=>"a188cc8c5f94c", "timestamp"=>"2009-08-11T06:21:22Z", "pending_reason"=>"none", "build"=>"997644", "transaction_type"=>"none", "error_codes"=>"10001", "version"=>"52.0", "ack"=>"Failure", "message"=>"Internal Error", "reason_code"=>"none", "payment_type"=>"none"}, @test=true, @authorization=nil, @cvv_result={"code"=>nil, "message"=>nil}, @message="Internal Error", @success=false, @fraud_review=false, @avs_result={"code"=>nil, "postal_match"=>nil, "street_match"=>nil, "message"=>nil}>
```

I'd LOVE it if someone could help!!!

Comment: I know this is long time ago but how did you get hold of the XML request. I am trying to get the request data for debuggin purposes but I don't know how I can log that...

Comment: I don't really remember, but I think there is a flag you can set it ActiveMerchant.  If that doesn't work, whip out tcpdump or Wireshark.  You might also have luck getting the SOAP gem to print out the output.  Good luck.

Comment: hehe, never mind I found it short after. You can set a wiredump_device e.g. to a log file and then the requests get copied in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I have are long-shot possibilities.

The interface could have gone down for unannounced reasons after you authorized. Similar thing happened on the 3rd, returning 10001s.

Could be related to https://ppmts.custhelp.com/cgi-bin/ppdts.cfg/php/enduser/std_adp.php?p_faqid=169

I'd also try reauthorizing with a small amount, but it should have given a different error if that was the problem.

Though it shouldn't make a difference if the auth succeeded, you haven't shown us the authorize transaction.

Comment: Thank you so much, I wasn't aware you couldn't use one of the standard test account numbers like every other payment gateway.  I've been banging my head against the wall for the past 3 days.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

Use non standard credit card number .

I was using standard credit card number '4111111111111111' and getting the 10001 error.

Used "4024007148673576" and it works for me.

Comment: I had the exact same problem, and was using the 41111... number. I used "402400714867357" and it works fine now. My CVV number was "111."